# Determine what Meteor methods are defined by the server

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to automate a Meteor app available online (namely, Meteor.com's account management - to add a collaborator to all 170+ organizations I'm a member of).

I've researched [reverse engineering Meteor apps](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/howtos/Automating_any_Meteor_app_you_find_on_the_web) but haven't been able to figure out correctly from DDP messages what methods are available on the server.

Meteor methods can be seen among the WebSocket frames by looking for `"msg":"method"`. For example, if you log into https://meteor.com, go to Organizations, and add a username to an organization in your Meteor account, you can see this in the WebSocket frame:

```
{
    "msg":"method",
    "method":"addOrganizationMember",
    "params":["jspdf", "splendido"],
    "id": "2"
}
```

(If the output looks uglier than that, vote for the Chrome team to implement this [feature request for prettifying WebSocket frame dumps](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=488978).) That method name, however, failed when running `Meteor.call('addOrganizationMember', 'jspdf', 'splendido')` in the console, with an error that the method wasn't found (404).

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to check if the method exists first & then if it does, make the call?

I think you'd want something like:

```
if (Meteor.server.method_handlers.addOrganizationMember) { 
  Meteor.call('addOrganizationMember', 'jspdf', 'splendido')
})
```

For client methods, it'd be `Meteor.connection._methodHandlers`

Hopefully I understood, set me straight if I didn't.

Comment: I'm on the client side, in the console, trying to figure out what methods exist on the server. `Meteor.connection._methodHandlers` is interesting! It doesn't display that addOrganizationMember method however. I've updated the question.

Comment: Ohhh, gotcha. A wonky way of doing that would be to manually publish the `method_handlers` to the client on startup or something. I don't think server-only methods would ever be published to the client as that could invite trouble.

Comment: So I don't control the server; trying to reverse engineer [an existing app](https://www.meteor.com/account-settings/organizations). When the client code executes `Meteor.call`, those parameters must be sniffable somehow. I've set up a spy on Meteor.call (`Meteor.call = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
}`), but it didn't yield anything when adding a user to an organization.